# How to check if a value in a dictionary has duplicates?

Tags: swift, hashmap

The algorithm below checks to see if an array has at least two or more duplicates. It uses a dictionary to store the occurrences; the time complexity is linear because it has to traverse the dictionary to see if a key occurs twice. In swift, how can I look up a value to see if it occurs more than twice in constant time ?

```
 func containsDuplicate(_ nums: [Int]) -> Bool {
        var frequencyTable = [Int:Int]()
        
        for num in nums {
            frequencyTable[num] = (frequencyTable[num] ?? 0 ) + 1
        }
        
        
        for value in frequencyTable.values{
            if value >= 2 {
                return true
            }
            
        }
        return false
    }
    
    containsDuplicate([1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4])
```

Comment: Note that while your function can be optimised, the time complexity cannot be any better than linear. In the worst case, you must at least look at every element once to see if it contains a duplicate.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48240200/1187415 for a simple solution using a `Set`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second loop is not necessary if the first loop checks if the current element has already been inserted before, and returns from the function in that case:

```
func containsDuplicate(_ nums: [Int]) -> Bool {
    var frequencyTable = [Int:Int]()
    for num in nums {
        if frequencyTable[num] != nil {
            return true
        }
        frequencyTable[num] = 1
    }
    return false
}
```

Then it becomes apparent that we don't need a dictionary, a *set* is sufficient:

```
func containsDuplicate(_ nums: [Int]) -> Bool {
    var seen = Set<Int>()
    for num in nums {
        if seen.contains(num) {
            return true
        }
        seen.insert(num)
    }
    return false
}
```

This can be further simplified: The “insert and check if element was already present” operation can be done in a single call:

```
func containsDuplicate(_ nums: [Int]) -> Bool {
    var seen = Set<Int>()
    for num in nums {
        if !seen.insert(num).inserted {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

This is similar to the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48240200/1187415)

```
return nums.count != Set(nums).count
```

but possibly more efficient: The function returns immediately when a duplicate element has been detected.

Finally we can make the function generic, so that it works with all arrays of a hashable type:

```
func containsDuplicate<T: Hashable>(_ array: [T]) -> Bool {
    var seen = Set<T>()
    for element in array {
        if !seen.insert(element).inserted {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Example:

```
print(containsDuplicate([1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4])) // true
print(containsDuplicate(["A", "X"])) // false
```

Or as an extension for arbitrary collections of a hashable type:

```
extension Collection where Element: Hashable {
    func containsDuplicate() -> Bool {
        var seen = Set<Element>()
        for element in self {
            if !seen.insert(element).inserted {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
    
print([1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4].containsDuplicate())
print(["A", "X"].containsDuplicate())
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the approaches !!!!

Comment: Please explain what this part of the code does ?                                                           
        if frequencyTable[num] != nil {
            return true
        }
        frequencyTable[num] = 1
    }

Comment: @TomHiddleston: `frequencyTable[num]` returns a non-nil value if the dictionary already has an entry for the key `num`. In that case the function can return `true` because it means that a duplicate entry has been found. Otherwise `frequencyTable[num]` is set to one.

Comment: Thanks. Does this part  frequencyTable[num] = 1 populate the dictionary if it has not  seen any key-value pair in the dictionary ? I come from a python background

Comment: @TomHiddleston: You can read about Swift dictionaries here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID113 and here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to know if it has duplicate, you can use use set and compare the length.

```
func containsDuplicate(_ nums: [Int]) -> Bool {
return Set(nums).count != nums.count
}
```

like this examples, because the set remove the duplicate values.

Comment: why not simply `return Set(nums).count != nums.count`

Comment: yes, you are right.